# How to know if a SCR is still working?

Tags: scr, continuity

I'm using a TIC116 to control the power over an electric grill. However, I didn't use a heatsink and it got very warm. On the data it says that its upper limit is 110 °C.

I suspect that the gate is not doing its job as expected, I think I have a leakage current. To test it, I tried with a continuity probe on my multimeter and it showed indeed continuity between gate and cathode. What does it mean? Is there another way to test it?

Comment: Read this.. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-7/silicon-controlled-rectifier-scr/ You can take it out and test it with a dummy load and gate drive too.

Answer (score 2):

A SCR has a PNPN doting scheme. So, between gate and cathode, there is a single PN junction and that one has to have continuity at a voltage drop of about 0.7V – same as a simple PN diode.

You have to measure between anode and cathode to check if the SCR conducts when it hasn't a gate current. Without an oscilloscope, you have to de-solder it to do a simple conductivity test.

Comment: Ok, it has continuity between gate and cathode (although it has not the 0.7V voltage when probing between them), and there is not continuity between K and A. I was not clear enough, but I want to know if is it possible that the gate is "conducting" through it instead of anode, because I have a resistor sharing the node of anode and it goes from anode to gate (to switch it).

Comment: The gate **must** be conducting, but it doesn't do so instead of the anode, but in addition to it. If your gate resistor burnt out, you may have reached the gate current limit (usually several 100mA) and burnt out the gate-cathode PN junction. This is likely the case if you cannot measure the 0.7V drop between gate and cathode.